# CS50 Assignment Issue; expected identifier or '('

Tags: c, cs50

I am copying and pasting this example code into the CS50 IDE,

file name test.c:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

for (int i = 0; i < 10, i++)
{
printf("test this");
}
```

I am getting the following error when I try to compile:

```
   ~/workspace/pset1/ $ make test

clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow    test.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o test
test.c:4:1: error: expected identifier or '('


for (int i = 0; i < 10, i++)

^
1 error generated.
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

I have looked and all answers I found contained syntax errors, but I have been copying / pasting example code after hitting this wall.

Comment: `i < 10, i++)` the comma should be a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

If that's your *entire* file, I think you'll find that the code has to go inside a function of some description, probably `main`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf ("test this\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You'll see a couple of other changes I've made which should make it "better":

- Repairing the `for` loop by replacing the comma with a semicolon.
- Adding a newline to the output string.
- Removing unnecessary headers (at least for *this* bit of code).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you - I needed to encase the loop in a function, and had the syntax error in the loop itself (a comma instead of a semi colon).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, C syntax requires semi-colons in for loops. Your for should be:

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)

Answer (score 0):

In for loops like this one, you need to use semicolons not commas. I has to be this:

```c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
printf("test this");
}
```

Not this:

```c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

for (int i = 0; i < 10, i++)
{
printf("test this");
}
```

As you can see, you have to use semicolons not commas after the

```c
i < 10
```

part.

Answer (score 0):

You used a comma, you need to use a semi colon in loop because c requires you do that.